# Python 2 - parse tab-delimited text file data into a list

Tags: python, list, csv

Please help me with what I think is my fundamental misunderstanding of lists and csv.

I have a text file of tab-delimited data (this is why I am using csv). It has a header row with 4 headings, and then 40 rows of data. I am trying to create a programme that will search the content of the text file and when a match is found will then print that row of data.

My first step is to create a list from the text file.

```
import csv

list=[] #create a new empty list
with open('data.txt','rb') as f:
    next(f) #skip heading row in text file (I cannot get csv.Dictreader instead to work as an alternative to this step)
    data = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t') #read text file with csv
    for row in data:
        list.append(row) #add the data from the text file to the list
```

When I run this programme as it is, I can type `print list` and it prints the contents of the text file, each row enclosed in a []. When I type `print row` it prints the LAST row entry in the text file. When I type `print row[0]` it prints the first column of this last row, and so on for row[1], row[2] and row[3]. When I type `print len(list)` it returns '40' which is the number of rows excluding the header.

I cannot print any of the other rows from the text file. Have I done something wrong in creating my list? How can I access other rows and check that I have created my list correctly?

I am having problems with what I think are the next steps, and I want to make sure that I have got this first step correct! I have read all the documentation I can find and all vaguely-related stack overflow queries and I just do not seem to understand this. I would really appreciate some help!

Edit: I have been asked to explain what I am trying to use this for.

I have a text file (data.txt). It has rows of tab-delimited data under four columns.

I want to make a search function so that:
The user inputs which column to search by
The user inputs a search term
The programme searches the list to find a match
The programme then prints the whole row containing the matching data.

E.g.
Name  Age Address Job
Marks 49  Manchester   Teacher
Smith 52  Somerset    Banker
Williams  83  Kent    Student

To do this I think I need to make the text file into a list that has been parsed with csv (because the data is tab-delimited). Then I think I should use `name = row[0]` `age = row[1]` and so on to complete my search function.

I am having trouble with understanding how the list function works in terms of row[0] etc.

Comment: Pl share what exactly you are trying to achieve, what you plan to do with the List. The post below will help you read your file. If you need to do additional operations, there are powerful libraries such a Pandas which can be used.

Comment: @AmritaSawant I have edited the original post if that helps. I have not heard about libraries such as a Pandas and I will look it up now, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `csv` anyway? You're only splitting the lines.

I made myself a test file like that:

```
header1 header2 header3 header4
row10   row11   row12   row13
row20   row21   row22   row23
row30   row32   row32   row33
row40   row42   row42   row43
row50   row52   row52   row53
row60   row62   row62   row63
```

And some simple lines to access each element:

```
with open('data.txt','r') as f:    
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    for line in lines:
        elements = line.strip().split("\t")
        print elements, len(elements)
```

The result output is:

```
['row10', 'row11', 'row12', 'row13'] 4
['row20', 'row21', 'row22', 'row23'] 4
['row30', 'row32', 'row32', 'row33'] 4
['row40', 'row42', 'row42', 'row43'] 4
['row50', 'row52', 'row52', 'row53'] 4
['row60', 'row62', 'row62', 'row63'] 4
```

That way you can add each entry of `elements` to a new array (like your `list`) and continue working with that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

I thought I need to use csv because of the search function I want to create: the user selects the header they want to search, inputs the search term, the programme then finds a match and prints the whole row.

This is what confuses me about what I have now. The data returned when I enter row[0], row[1] etc is correctly split by tab-delimiting. But why is it only the last row of the data?

Because I think what you have suggested - I don't just need to split the lines I also need to distinguish the tab-delimited data within the lines?

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion out, @dersvenhesse! I think I have a more precise question for you without all of my extra confusing details:

If I put `print elements[0]` instead of `print elements, len(elements)` then when I run it my programme prints column 1 for all 40 entries.
If when I am running this programme I then input `print elements[0]` it only prints out column 1 for the last entry.

Why is this?

Comment: @emiden Sorry, I think I still don't get your problem exactly. When I run my program with `print elements[0]` instead of `print elements` the output is `row10` ... `row60`. So that's what it's supposed to do. Now where is the issue there? Are you making sure the indentation is correct when printing?

Answer (score 1):

There could be simpler ways to do this, however I am comfortable with Pandas so using it here. This program is just a sketch. You will need to modify to optimize it. for eg. if you need to search through columns and records, you will need to modify the func with some kind of 'regex' (re package) logic. Let me know if you need more help.

I create a .txt file

```
        name    state   game
        john    CA      soccer
        peter   CA      soccer
        kate    CA      basketball
        ed      CA      football


    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv("C:/Amrita/test.txt", header=None,     delim_whitespace=True,names=['name','state','game'])
    def myfunc(data): 
            prompt1 = "Enter column name: \n"
            prompt2 = "Enter search term: \n"
            user_input1 = raw_input(prompt1)
            user_input2 = raw_input(prompt2)
            print df[(df[user_input1] == user_input2)]
    myfunc(df)  

    Enter column name: 
    game
    Enter search term: 
    soccer
    name   state    game
    john    CA      soccer
    peter   CA      soccer
```